# Triangle shaped ImageView with onclick

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I have two rectangular images like,
[image]

I need to create a layout that's split the screen diagonally into two parts with different images, as something like this :

[image]

how can I create this layout ? I must create a custom imageview ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just edit the two images together into one, before adding it to your application?

Comment: I get my images from a web service.